# Showing sum at the bottom of a html table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables `App`, `Loan` and `Payment`.

I've selected all the data from the three tables using:

```
SELECT applicant.*, loan.*, payment.* 
FROM (applicant INNER JOIN loan ON applicant.app_trn = loan.app_trn) 
INNER JOIN payment ON loan.loan_reff_id= payment.loan_reff_id ORDER by app_fname
```

At the very bottom of the table, I would like to display the total amount owed by loan.

Can someone please aid me in this, the tables are as follows:

- `App`: `app_id`, `name`, `address`;
- `Loan`: `app_id`, `loan_id`, loan amount  owed;
- `Payment`: `loan_id`, payment amount.

I want to be able to show the total of the amount owed at the bottom of the table.

Comment: We might need some more details. Are you using php? Show us the code that you are using to generate the table from the data that you have.

Comment: SELECT applicant.*, loan.*, payment.*
 FROM 
  (applicant INNER JOIN loan
   ON applicant.app_trn = loan.app_trn)
   INNER JOIN payment
   ON loan.loan_reff_id= payment.loan_reff_id
   ORDER by app_fname

Comment: I use that to display all the information from the three tables

Comment: And yes I am using php as well

Comment: I don't understand your column names for the `Loan` and `Payment` tables - is it one column called `loan amount owed` and one called `payment amount`?

Comment: yes in the loan table there is a column named loan_amount_owed and yes payment does have a column called payment_amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
   SELECT applicant.*, loan.*, payment.* 
   FROM (applicant INNER JOIN loan ON applicant.app_trn = loan.app_trn) 
   INNER JOIN payment ON loan.loan_reff_id= payment.loan_reff_id ORDER by app_fname
)
union
(    
   SELECT 
       0 as app_id,
       0 as name,
       0 as address,
       0 as loan_id,
       sum(loan amount owed),
       0 as payment amount
   FROM (
       SELECT applicant.*, loan.*, payment.* 
       FROM (applicant INNER JOIN loan ON applicant.app_trn = loan.app_trn) 
       INNER JOIN payment ON loan.loan_reff_id= payment.loan_reff_id ORDER by app_fname
        ) t
)
```

The idea is using union couple with the aggregate function sum.